# Why is this double-checked lock implemented with a separate wrapper class?

Tags: java, thread-safety, lazy-loading

When I was reading Wikipedias's article about [Double Checked Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) idiom, I'm confused about its implementation:

```
public class FinalWrapper<T> {
    public final T value;
    public FinalWrapper(T value) { 
        this.value = value; 
    }
} 
public class Foo {
    private FinalWrapper<Helper> helperWrapper = null;

    public Helper getHelper() {
        FinalWrapper<Helper> wrapper = helperWrapper;

        if (wrapper == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (helperWrapper == null) {
                    helperWrapper = new FinalWrapper<Helper>(new Helper());
                }
                wrapper = helperWrapper;
            }
        }
        return wrapper.value;
    }
}
```

I simply don't understand why we need to create wrapper. Isn't this enough ?

```
if (helperWrapper == null) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if (helperWrapper == null) {
            helperWrapper = new FinalWrapper<Helper>(new Helper());
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because using wrapper can speed up initialization because wrapper is stored on stack and helperWrapper is stored in heap?

Comment: @pst: I think he is asking about the additional `wrapper` local variable that holds a copy of `helperWrapper`.

Comment: @casablanca Oh, hum, missed that angle entirely.... now I'm confused, due to the rest of the wording of the question. "I don't understand why we need to create a wrapper." :(

Comment: Great question by the way. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't this enough ?
>
> ```
> if (helperWrapper == null) {
>      synchronized(this) {
>        if (helperWrapper == null) {
>           helperWrapper = new FinalWrapper<Helper>(new Helper());
>        }
>      }
> }
> ```

No this isn't enough.

Above, first check for `helperWrapper == null` is not thread safe. It may return false (seeing non-null instance) for some thread "too early", pointing to not fully constructed helperWrapper object.

The very [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) you refer to, explains this issue step-by-step:

> For example, consider the following sequence of events:
>
> 1. Thread A notices that the value is not initialized, so it obtains the lock and begins to initialize the value.
> 2. Due to the semantics of some programming languages, the code generated by the compiler is allowed to update the shared variable to
>      point to a partially constructed object before A has finished
>      performing the initialization.
> 3. Thread B notices that the shared variable has been initialized (or so it appears), and returns its value. Because thread B believes the
>      value is already initialized, it does not acquire the lock. If B uses
>      the object before all of the initialization done by A is seen by B
>      (either because A has not finished initializing it or because some of
>      the initialized values in the object have not yet percolated to the
>      memory B uses (cache coherence)), the program will likely crash.

Note *semantics of some programming languages* mentioned above is exactly the semantic of Java as of version 1.5 and higher. Java Memory Model (JSR-133) explicitly allows for such behavior - search the web for more details on that if you're interested.

> Is it because using wrapper can speed up initialization because wrapper is stored on stack and helperWrapper is stored in heap?

No, above isn't the reason.

The reason is thread safety. Again, semantic of Java 1.5 and higher (as defined in Java Memory Model) guarantees that any thread will be able to access only properly initialized Helper instance from wrapper due to the fact that it is a final field initialized in constructor - see [JLS 17.5 Final Field Semantics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5).

Comment: I believe you mean 'It may return _false_ for some thread...' in the text after the `helperWrapper == null` sentence.

Comment: @Cyberfox you are right - thanks for catching this! I corrected the typo

Comment: "It may return false (seeing non-null instance) for some thread "too early", pointing to not fully constructed instance of Helper." <-- How can a "not fully constructed instance" be leaked here? :(

Comment: @pst I meant to say instance of helper wrapper here - will correct that typo

Comment: I don't see how that's true. Thanks to final it is guaranteed that either `helperWrapper/wrapper` are null **or** we see the correct value of the final variable. The compiler is explicitly **NOT** allowed to publish an object whose final fields have not been set. And if it were the additional local variable would do exactly nothing. So the code should work just as well without the additional local.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this misses the point of the question. If, as you say, `helperWrapper` can refer to a partially constructed FinalWrapper object, how does copying the reference to the local variable `wrapper` help exactly? Now `wrapper` refers to the partially constructed object, and it has the same problems.

Comment: @waxwing I agree with you that this answer is missing the main reason why the temp variable is required. See my answer for details.

Comment: I don't agree with this explanation. Since `FinalWrapper.value` is final, JMM does not allow reordering of object initialization and reference observation. In contrary, any observation of the reference is guaranteed to return a fully initialized object.

Answer (score 3):

Simply using helperWrapper for both null checks and the return statement could fail due to read reordering allowed under the Java Memory Model.

Here is the example scenario:

1. The first `helperWrapper == null` (racy read) test evaluates to false, i.e. helperWrapper is not null.
2. The final line,`return helperWrapper.value` (racy read) results in a NullPointerException, i.e. helperWrapper is null

How did that happen? The Java Memory Model allows those two racy reads to be reordered, because there was no barrier prior to the read i.e. no "happens-before" relationship. (See [String.hashCode example](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ru/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html))

Notice that before you can read `helperWrapper.value`, you must implicitly read the `helperWrapper` reference itself. So the guarantees provided by `final` semantics that helperWrapper is fully instantiated do not apply, because they **only** apply when helperWrapper is not null.

Comment: it means that the action set helpWrapper to wrapper disallow the reads reorder due to the final semantic?

Comment: @GhostFlying no. the reads of helperWrapper cannot be reordered when we write `return wrapper.value` because it is no longer reading helperWrapper.

Comment: Experiment in this article https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_arm shows that this reordering is really possible on some processor architectures. See Correctness/ARM/Unsafe DCL+Safe Singleton (failure), which is equivalent to final wrapper without temporary variable. See also the table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that the reason `wrapper` is used is that reading an immutable object (all fields are final) is an atomic operation.

If `wrapper` is null, then it's not yet an immutable object, and we have to fall into the `synchronized` block.

If `wrapper` is not-null then we are *guaranteed* to have a fully constructed `value` object, so we can return it.

In your code, the `null` check could be done without actually reading the referenced object, and so not triggering the atomicity of the operation.  I.e. the operation could have initialized `helperWrapper` in preparation for passing the result of `new Helper()` to the constructor, but the constructor has not been called yet.

Now I would presume that the subsequent code in your example would read `return helperWrapper.value;` which *should* trigger an atomic reference read, guaranteeing that the constructor completes, but it's entirely possible ('*semantics of some programming languages*') that the compiler is allowed to optimize that to not perform an atomic read, and thus it would return an incompletely initialized `value` object under the exact right circumstances.

Performing the barrier using a local variable and a reference copy forces the read and write to be atomic, and ensures that the code is thread-safe.

I believe the key understanding is that immutable reference reads and writes are atomic, so assignment to another variable is atomic, but null testing might not be.